# I'm running a deep learning model on Colab. I make some changes to train.py but I want to sync folders with Drive (where my code originally lies)

Tags: session, deep-learning, model, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

My deep learning code is on my google drive inside a folder. I dont have access to a local GPU so I use Google Colab Pro to train my models. I mount my drive and run/edit/train the code.

When I make some changes to train.py or any other file in a particular colab session, I want those changes to reflect back to the original version in my g-drive. How do I sync my colab session with my g-drive?

I would like to sync the entire code folder of colab session with the one in g-drive.

Internet has lot of solutions for mounting drive to colab but nothing in the reverse direction.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.google/products/drive/drive-for-desktop/amp/) help?

Comment: @null even on the same device. My code generates patches from images and stores them into folders called train_ds & val_ds. Now the issue is, I can see these train_ds/val_ds folders on my colab session, expand them to see how many patches each has, count the no. of patches in a code cell, etc. I can see train_ds on my drive too. It gets synced quickly, as it should. But for val_ds, I can't see this on my drive. Should not happen as my code has been mounted from the drive. Is it an internet problem? The train_ds is so big (32k patches) that val_ds doesn't sync on time?

Comment: It's unlikely that its due to an internet connection, as the speed should be suffiicient. Can you confirm that you output `val_ds` under the mount root ? or there is no clash of names cuz I suspect that it should be due to `val_ds` exported out of mounted path.